# How to chain non-blocking action in CompletionStage.exceptionally

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, java-8, completable-future

I am writing a Play2 application service method in Java that should do the following. Asynchronously call method A, and if that fails, asynchronously call method B.

To illustrate assume this interface for the backend called by the service:

```
public interface MyBackend {
    CompletionStage<Object> tryWrite(Object foo);
    CompletionStage<Object> tryCleanup(Object foo);
}
```

So in my service method, I want to return a Future that can complete with these:

- Success of tryWrite completed
- Fail of tryWrite and Success of tryCleanup completed and failing with exception of tryWrite()

(Note: Of course tryWrite() could do any cleanup itself, this is a simplified example to illustrate a problem)

The implementation of a service calling the backend like this seems difficult to me because the CompletionStage.exceptionally() method does not allow Composing.

Version 1:

```
public class MyServiceImpl {
    public CompletionStage<Object> tryWriteWithCleanup(Object foo) {

        CompletionStage<Object> writeFuture = myBackend.tryWrite(foo)
            .exceptionally((throwable) -> {
                CompletionStage<Object> cleanupFuture = myBackend.tryCleanup(foo);
                throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
        });
        return writeFuture;
    }
}
```

So version 1 calls tryCleanup(foo) in a non-blocking way, but the CompletionStage returned by tryWriteWithCleanup() will not wait for cleanupFuture to complete. How to change this code to return a future from the service that would also wait for completion of cleanupFuture?

Version 2:

```
public class MyServiceImpl {
    public CompletionStage<Object> tryWriteWithCleanup(Object foo) {

        final AtomicReference<Throwable> saveException = new AtomicReference<>();
        CompletionStage<Object> writeFuture = myBackend
            .tryWrite(foo)
            .exceptionally(t -> {
                saveException.set(t);
                // continue with cleanup
                return null;
            })
            .thenCompose((nil) -> {
                // if no cleanup necessary, return
                if (saveException.get() == null) {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                }
                return CompletionStage<Object> cleanupFuture = myBackend.tryCleanup(foo)
                    .exceptionally(cleanupError -> {
                        // log error
                        return null;
                    })
                    .thenRun(() -> {
                        throw saveException.get();
                    });
        });
        return writeFuture;
    }
}
```

Version2 uses an external AtomicReference to store the failure, and makes the asynchronous second call in another thenCompose() block, if there was a failure.

All my other attempts to do so ended up so unwieldy that I don't want to paste them here.

Comment: You could always call `tryCleanup()` synchronously within `exceptionally()`

Comment: I do not want to block a thread in exceptionally

Comment: FYI, you should not add "solved" in the question title: this will be indicated by the fact you accepted an answer. I thus rolled it back to the previous title. Thanks for the accept by the way :-)

Comment: Hey @tkruse! Thanks a lot for the bounty! First time someone awards me one of this kind. And congrats for your fast progress and investment on SO during the last few months!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately `CompletionStage`/`CompletableFuture` does not provide exception handling API's with composition.

You can work around this though by relying on a [`handle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) with a `BiFunction` that returns a `CompletionStage`. This will give you nested stages (`CompletionStage<CompletionStage<Object>>`) that you can the "*unnest*" using `compose(identity())`:

```
public CompletionStage<Object> tryWriteWithCleanup(Object foo) {
    return myBackend.tryWrite(foo)
            .handle((r, e) -> {
                if (e != null) {
                    return myBackend.tryCleanup(foo)
                            .handle((r2, e2) -> {
                                // Make sure we always return the original exception
                                // but keep track of new exception if any,
                                // as if run in a finally block
                                if (e2 != null) {
                                    e.addSuppressed(e2);
                                }
                                // wrapping in CompletionException  behaves as if
                                // we threw the original exception
                                throw new CompletionException(e);
                            });
                }
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(r);
            })
            .thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is also a correct solution to my problem. I like that since there is only one future involved, there is no risk of forgetting to complete a future.

Comment: @Holger, if you do that, when `e != null` you will actually return a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Object>>`, and that one will be completed before the inner one (the cleanup) completes. The OP required to _return a future from the service that would also wait for completion of cleanupFuture_.

Comment: Oh right, I was focused on the fact that the operation never completes normally, but yes, it still has the formal type of a `CompletionStage`.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply wait for the completion inside the handler:

```
public CompletionStage<Object> tryWriteWithCleanup(Object foo) {
    return myBackend.tryWrite(foo).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        myBackend.tryCleanup(foo).toCompletableFuture().join();
        throw new CompletionException(throwable);
    });
}
```

This will defer the completion of the result `CompletionStage` to the completion of the cleanup stage. Using `CompletionException` as wrapper will make the wrapping transparent to the caller.

However, it has some drawbacks. While the framework might utilize the thread while waiting or spawn a compensation thread, if it is a worker thread, the blocked thread might be the caller thread if the stage returned by `tryWrite` happens to be already completed when entering `exceptionally`. Unfortunately, there is no `exceptionallyAsync` method. You may use `handleAsync` instead, but it will complicate the code while still feeling like a kludge.

Further, exceptions thrown by the cleanup may shadow the original failure.

A cleaner solution may be a bit more involved:

```
public CompletionStage<Object> tryWriteWithCleanup(Object foo) {

    CompletableFuture<Object> writeFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    myBackend.tryWrite(foo).whenComplete((obj,throwable) -> {
        if(throwable==null)
            writeFuture.complete(obj);
        else
            myBackend.tryCleanup(foo).whenComplete((x,next) -> {
                try {
                    if(next!=null) throwable.addSuppressed(next);
                }
                finally {
                    writeFuture.completeExceptionally(throwable);
                }
        });
    });
    return writeFuture;
}
```

This simply creates a `CompletableFuture` manually, allowing to control its completion, which will happen either directly by the action chained to `tryWrite`’s stage in the successful case, or by the action chained to the cleanup stage in the exceptional case. Note that the latter takes care about chaining a possible subsequent cleanup exception via `addSuppressed`.

Comment: Why do you wrap the `addSuppressed()` in a `try`/`finally`? If it fails it would indicate a serious bug, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Didier L: since we don’t know what the main action and the cleanup action do, they may throw the same exception instance generated and reused by an underlying system (e.g. database). Then `addSuppressed` may fail due to a self-suppression attempt. Apparently, it only fails for identical exceptions but is fine with loops so a pre-test `throwable!=next` would do, but I just used what I saw once in a compiled try-with-resource construct. But this is compiler specific, the last time I checked, ECJ generated a pre-test, current `javac` seems not to care about preventing self-suppression at all.

Comment: BTW: As you said, I do not want a thread waiting for tryCleanup(), not even a worker thread (i think those must be protected, too).
You get extra-points for thinking of the try-catch. In your place I'd reformat the code in your second answer to make it more readable, even if it takes more vertical space

Comment: Choosing the other answer only because there is less risk of forgetting to complete the returned Future in more involved code.